# Access very first tag (xml tag) of a svg file with java

Tags: java, html, xml, svg

How can I access the very first tag of a svg file (the tag < ?xml version...>).

e.g. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000" height="1000" version="1.0">
.
.
. 
</svg>
```

I would like to recover the very first node :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

The conventionnal methods do not work, like :

doc.getFirstchild() or doc.getElementsByTagName(tagname)

Do you now a way to get it (I need to be able to access this element, not just put something before it) and to modify it at the same time ?

Comment: You should really ask a new question instead of completely changing the original one.

Comment: Look at the post before the edit, it is exaclty the same. And even if I would do that (I already did in fact) there is ALWAYS a person who marks it as duplicated, weather it is not. So...

Comment: OK, I'll delete my answer as it does not fit anymore.